# Mounting drive in Ubuntu after reboot - error

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am trying to mount a 4TB drive on an ubuntu box  and trying various things to mount it after a reboot. This is what my lsblk looks like.

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0   190M  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0 189.8M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda2    8:2    0   9.3G  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0   9.3G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sda3    8:3    0   229G  0 part  
  └─md2   9:2    0 228.9G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sdb1    8:17   0   3.7T  0 part  
sdc       8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sdc1    8:33   0   3.7T  0 part  
sdd       8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sdd1    8:49   0   3.7T  0 part  
sde       8:64   0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sde1    8:65   0   190M  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0 189.8M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sde2    8:66   0   9.3G  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0   9.3G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sde3    8:67   0   229G  0 part  
  └─md2   9:2    0 228.9G  0 raid1 /
```

I have tried:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /data
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I have also tried

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb /data
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

The error message that it's not a valid NTFS doesn't make sense since it was working fine until the reboot.

I have tried several of the suggestions on AskUbuntu and Superuser to no luck. 
I am at a loss and way out of my league here, could someone help what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
file -s /dev/sdb1
```

for see how (or if ...) the system detects the filesystem. Also, you should consider connecting it on a Windows machine and try running a checkdisk on the volume.

Comment: Tx, I did run file -s command and got this response `/dev/sdb1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=92668043-997c-4fd7-b1db-bd2db17a1a19 (extents) (large files) (huge files)`

Comment: So, /dev/sdb1 is an **ext4** filesystem, not a **NTFS** one. Just `mount /dev/sdb1 /data` should suffice. You can also try specify the filesystem: `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /data`. If all that fail, you could try fsck the filesystem: `fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1`.